# How to create a Offline service Chatbot?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I want to create a Offline chatbot for my personal purpose at home.
So I don't want to use API.AI or WIT.AI or any other Online API's which support my purpose.

Is there any way I can create a chatbot from scratch for specific service purpose (any programming language implementation is fine)

Comment: That's too broad. Writing a chatbot from scratch without using any online resources would be impractical, as you need huge amount of training data.

Comment: check http://rasa.com/

Answer (score 2):

To create your own chatbot, you will have to train it. If you want it to be offline you will have to train it on your own computer. Below are some options for doing this.

When you say 'from scratch' are you willing to use libraries? If so this one looks like it could be the most straight forward for training a chat bot: https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot I believe this library is completely offline so everything runs on your machine. They provide corpuses to train on or you can provide your own.

The harder route will be training without a specific chatbot library. You will still need to use a NLP or machine learning library. Here are some links for training chatbots with tensorflow:

https://chatbotsmagazine.com/contextual-chat-bots-with-tensorflow-4391749d0077?gi=77541bcf0a26

This one may be oversimplified, but seems like a good intro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJDEOWLHYVo

You should be able to find many more resources through Google as well.